# is it possible in iphone-Reopen Native app after opening and closing map application or any other apple's app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

i want to create something  like this. open map application(means maps) then when maps closed reopen my application.also tell me if it is possible will it be possible in iphone OS 2.0. i know about weak linking of frameworks as apple did in mail composer sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Sorry.  When your application quits, either the user has to re-open it or another app has to relaunch it.  (This applies to OS3.1 and prior.)